# Is there a log go check who made a mongodb transaction?

Tags: mongodb

I see a mongodb update and dont know who and when it was made?is this logged in somewhere in mongodb?which logs and where can I check on who made this update?

Comment: where do you see this update?

Comment: its in a db collection named `db.getCollection('latest_fw_released')`

Answer (score 0):

> is this logged in somewhere in mongodb?

[MongoDB Enterprise](https://www.mongodb.com/products/mongodb-enterprise-advanced) includes an [auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/auditing/) capability for `mongod` and `mongos` instances. The auditing facility allows administrators and users to track system activity for deployments with multiple users and applications. See also [Tutorial: configure auditing](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-auditing/).

If your database is hosted on [MongoDB Atlas](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/), auditing is included natively. See [MongoDB Atlas: Database Auditing](https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/database-auditing/) for more information and steps to configure it.

If you're not using MongoDB Enterprise nor MongoDB Atlas, you can ensure all users to [authenticate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/authentication/) with their own user/password and have a controlled access. i.e. custom application that tracks user, operation and time.

Comment: am not looking to enable the logging,I am looking to see if it is already logged somewhere and check who made it,to be specific i see someone updated a database column,wanted to find out who it is?

Comment: No, it's not recorded by default (as of current v4.0.x). You would need to enable auditing feature as mentioned above for it.